# Is there a way to pass a parameter to google bigquery to be used in their "IN" function

Tags: node.js, parameters, google-bigquery

I'm currently writing an app that accesses google bigquery via their "@google-cloud/bigquery": "^2.0.6" library.  In one of my queries I have a where clause where i need to pass a list of ids.  If I use UNNEST like in their example and pass an array of strings, it works fine.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries

However, I have found that UNNEST can be really slow and just want to use IN on its own and pass in a string list of ids.  No matter what format of string list I send, the query returns null results.  I think this is because of the way they convert parameters in order to avoid sql injection.  I have to use a parameter because I, myself want to avoid SQL injection attacks on my app.  If i pass just one id it works fine, but if i pass a list it blows up so I figure it has something to do with formatting, but I know my format is correct in terms of what IN would normally expect i.e. IN ('', '')

Has anyone been able to just pass a param to IN and have it work?  i.e. IN (@idParam)?

Comment: Sorry, that should have been IN ("id1", "id2")

Answer (score 1):

We declare params like this at the beginning of the script:

```
DECLARE var_country_ids ARRAY<INT64> DEFAULT [1,2,3];
```

and use like this:

```
WHERE if(var_country_ids is not null,p.country_id IN UNNEST(var_country_ids),true) AND ...
```

as you see we let `NULL` and `array` notation as well. We don't see issues with speed.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response!  However, I'm asking specifically about using the javascript/node api library to pass an array as a parameter to bigQuery and wondering if the parameter has to be used along with UNNEST in the query as I can't seem to get it to work with just IN